# Why elasticsearch return irrelevant results with operators "OR"?

Tags: elasticsearch

Below are the two documents:

**Document-1:**

```
{
  "type": "document",
  "name": "Meter testing practice",
  "id": "cd1269",  
  "tags": [ "METER TESTING PRACTICE" ]
}
```

**Document-2:**

```
{
  "type": "document",
  "name": "Single phase meter",
  "id": "cd1271",
  "tags": [ "SINGLE PHASE METER", "SINGLE PHASE METER INSTALLATION",
            "TOOLS FOR METER INSTALLATION" ]
}
```

**Query1:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "tags" : {
                "query" : "SINGLE PHASE METER"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When executing **query1**, it returns below results:

**Results:**

```
{
                "took": 0,
                "timed_out": false,
                "_shards": {
                    "total": 5,
                    "successful": 5,
                    "skipped": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                },
                "hits": {
                    "total": 2,
                    "max_score": 1.2655861,
                    "hits": [
                             {
                                 "_shard": "[document_org4][4]",
                                 "_node": "YgzzS4wzQQKpdHxvsbVzPA",
                                 "_index": "document_org4",
                                 "_type": "document",
                                 "_id": "cd1269",
                                 "_score": 1.2655861,
                                 "_source": {
                                     "tags": [ "METER TESTING PRACTICE" ],
                                     "type": "document",
                                     "name": "Meter testing practice",
                                     "id": "cd1269"
                                 }                          
                             },
                             {
                                 "_shard": "[document_org4][3]",
                                 "_node": "YgzzS4wzQQKpdHxvsbVzPA",
                                 "_index": "document_org4",
                                 "_type": "document",
                                 "_id": "cd1271",
                                 "_score": 0.8617958,
                                 "_source": {
                                     "tags": [ "SINGLE PHASE METER", "SINGLE PHASE METER INSTALLATION", "TOOLS FOR METER INSTALLATION" ],
                                     "type": "document",
                                     "name": "Single phase meter",
                                     "id": "cd1271"
                                 }
                             }
                             ]
                }
        }
```

as we can see that in the results **first document** has highest score, i didn't understand why this is happening. If we see the **second document**, it is more relevant than **first document**.

**Query2:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "tags" : {
                "query" : "SINGLE PHASE METER",
                "operator": "AND"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when executing **query2** it gives me the correct result as i expected. Please someone help me out...

Answer (score 0):

It's because the field is shorter. I'd recommend [reading up on BM25](https://www.elastic.co/blog/practical-bm25-part-2-the-bm25-algorithm-and-its-variables) (which is the current default scoring algorithm for ES.

You can use the [explain api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) in order to figure out what the individual components of the algorithm score like. This will help you figure out why one documents appears above an other

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are looking to filter out un-matching documents from the entire population because of the use of tags. It this scenario, you would be going for an exact match, right?
If that's the case I suggest you index your array datatype field as 'KEYWORD' first.
You could then go for a term query:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "match_all":{}
         },
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "must":[
                  {
                  "term": {
                    "tags.keyword": "single phase meter"
                  }
                }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You might want to normalize your keyword field if you ever want to aggregate or sort on it without encountering odd results. In this example, the field is normalized at index time to lower case.

```
...
tags:{
  "fields":{
        "keyword":{
          "type":"keyword"
        }
   }
}
...
```

For this example to work, you need to create a keyword field in your mapping. Remember that the keyword field is case sensitive. You need to have the exact same spelling at query time for it to match. If you don't normalize your input you would need to use the uppercase spelling.

```
...
"term": {
     "tags.keyword": "SINGLE PHASE METER"
}
....
```

Comment: Tried as you said but its not working. Given query returns empty results